# webpack babel and react simple example fails

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am trying webpack with React and Babel. I created a simple example:

components.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { render } from 'react-dom'

class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Hello/>, document.getElementById('test'));
export default Hello;
```

index.js:

```
import Hello from "components.jsx";
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Webpack, React and Babel example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>  </div>
  <div id="test"> </div>
  <script src="bundle.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I also installed all the necessary modules: babel-loader, babel-core babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react, react, react-dom.

However, when I typed "webpack" in this current folder, I always got error message:

> ERROR in ./index.js Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module
>   'components.jsx' in

It is such a simple example and I must make a huge dumb mistake. But I just cannot find it.

Thanks

Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to import a module by name, it's expected to be found under `node_modules`. That's probably not where you want it to be though, so you should import it via (a relative) path instead.

```
import Hello from "./components.jsx";
```

If the `index.js` and `components.jsx` files share a folder, the above will work. If they don't then you need to change `./` to point to the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, `index.js` and `components.jsx` are located in the same folder, if it is true, path should be the following

```
import Hello from "./components.jsx";
```